Board game where you built physical "bridges" to fish for resources from a pond
I am looking for a boardgame that I played some time between 1999 and 2005. The board was round and resembled a pond. Every player acted as a group of stone age people and you had three (maybe more) workers, that could do different things.
The main gig of the game was to build some kind of bridge out of wood (imagine something like jenga pieces) and stone (literal stones, pebbles, maybe 3cm in diameter) on wich you placed your fisherman token. Then at the end of the turn, a cardboard piece would rotate one turn that pushed resources around the pond. They would tend to migrate to the middle of the pond, so you were enouraged to build longer bridges. Whatever resources where under your bride (it had to have its base at the edge of the pond), you could take. These resources where small cardboard tokens in differnet colors and used to win the game or research (not entirely shure anymore).
There was also a wood camp and a stone camp which were used to gather the bridge building material.
The other to workers I remember were a clubman and a trader.
You could place your pieces either at your base, at the material camps or at other player bases and depending at which worker was where, different things happened.
If to clubmen where on the same space, they would just hit each other and nothing happened. If only one clubman was at a material camp it would grant one building material. If one clubman was at another players camp one could steal something from that player.
The fisherman could either fish at your own bridge or get one material at the camps.
If two traders met, player could trade (though I do not remember how). A single trader would probably also get building material from the camps.
I tried googling for it, but to no avail. There is a slight chance, that this was a self made game. But in my memory the production value of the board was to professional for that.


The game you're remembering is Burp, originally published by Heidelberger Spieleverlag in 1995 in German, and later by Mayfair Games in English.
By building docks out of planks and rocks to fish in the sea of knowledge, players collect various kinds of fruit.
They combine their fruit into specific fruit cocktails, to discover important inventions, which allow players to travel the path of knowledge. Inventions such as the wheel and fire enhance a players chances to acquire more of the fruit they need.
Fishermen, Traders and Fighters are then placed in the villages, the quarry or woods to collect materials (rock and wood), steal opponents rocks, and fish for knowledge.

It might help OP to see a picture of the board itself; https://cf.geekdo-images.com/S-1M0G8THV1qU_k39Q_sYg__imagepage/img/NsB5T_cC_QQZyeBjn-FD1EtqVYg=/fit-in/900x600/filters:no_upscale():strip_icc()/pic56959.jpg
